# UIView frame not updating in Swift 2.0/iOS 8.0 & iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to update y position of a View in Swift 2.0. But it's not happening. I am not using Auto layout. Here is my code:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    var frame : CGRect = self.frameView.frame
    frame.origin.y = -390
    //self.frameView.frame = frame
    self.frameView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)
    print(" frame \(self.frameView.frame)")
}
```

Although when I print frame it shows the updated value but change does not reflect. Any clue what I am missing?

Comment: code is in your 'viewDidLoad' method or 'viewWillAppear'? add code in your viewWillAppear not in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Is the view added on storyboard/xib?

Comment: self.frameView is your textview

Comment: When you say "I'm not using AutoLayout" what exactly do you mean? Did you create your view in Interface Builder? Have you tried doing... `print(self.constraints)`. Ignoring the fact that Auto Layout is there is not "not using Auto Layout".

Comment: BTW... you are probably using AutoLayout and you cannot change the frame of a view directly when you are using AutoLayout.

Comment: I am not using Autolayout feature in my App. I have disabled it. It is working in iOS 7 but not working in iOS 8 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that some other code changes the frame back and overrides your change. This is why you do not see the frame where you expect it to be. Use view debug to check the frame (3 rectangles button just below your code tab in xcode). Also you could set a symbolic breakpoint on the `UIView` `setFrame` method to check from where the frame is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update constraints after you change frames of the UIView at run time. Hopefully it should work.

```
self.view .needsUpdateConstraints()
self.view .needsUpdateConstraints()
self.view .setNeedsLayout()
self.view .layoutIfNeeded()
```

OR If you are not using AutoLayout then check if you are setting right AutoResizing Mask on Storyboard. You need to update AutoResizingMask Programatically. Example:-

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
```

Comment: Or just use AutoLayout properly :P

Comment: I am not using AutoLayout. My app is not using AutoLayout.

Comment: @TechBee please see my comment to your question. If you have not explicitly told your app that you absolutely are not using AutoLayout in every bit of UI (this is very difficult to do) then you are using AutoLayout.

Comment: I have disabled Autolayout in the App.

Answer (score 0):

I set the frame of the view instead of frameView and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the frame of view in func `layoutSubviews()` worked for me.